# javascript : after calling the splice() control comes out from the loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, array-splice

I have an array `rosters` and i want to alter this array according to some conditions. Here what I'm trying to do.

```
somefunction(callback) {
    for (var i in this.rosters) {
        var roster = this.rosters[i];
        if (roster.age > 7200) {
            this.rosters.splice(i, 1);
        } else {
            this.rosters[i].age = this.EMarshal.tu.getAgeOfTime(
                this.EMarshal.tu.getMyTime(
                    this.EMarshal.tu.getMyDate(roster.date), roster.shifttime
                )
            );
            console.log(this.rosters[i].age);
        }
    }
    callback();
}
```

When the the `if` condition is true and `splice` is been called, control comes out of from loop and call `callback()`. But i want to run the loop for each values in the array.

plz carefully notice that there are `rosters` and `roster` 2 different variables.

Any idea why its happening and the solution will be usefull.
Thanks

Comment: `and splice is been called, control comes out of form loop ` - you lost me there

Comment: it "from loop", now you ca ngo ahead. @thefourtheye

Comment: The problem is that you're modifying the list while iterating through it.

Comment: No i tried to store the indexes and run the splice for those index after the loop, same result i got. @Saposhiente

Comment: It's generally a bad idea to modify a list while you're looping over it. It would be better to accumulate a list of things to remove, then remove them after the loop finishes.

Comment: Strongly recommend read: [Why is using “for…in” with array iteration such a bad idea?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/500504/1048572)

Comment: when you splice an index less than _i_,  _i_ +1 becomes just _i_, then you increment, and thus skip over the old _i_ +1...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just because you are trying to alter the array on which you are iterating.
So, just ad some logic to store the indexes as you have said you have tried.
Here is one suggestion 
before getting into loop `var index = [];`
then your if condition

```
if (roster.age > 7200) {
  index.push(i);
}
```

and then after the loop, remove those indexes from `rosters`

```
for (var j = index.length - 1; j > -1; j-- ) {
  console.log(j);
  this.rosters.splice(index[j], 1);
}
```

Remember to iterate the index from `last index` otherwise you will remove the `1st index` and the trying to remove the `last index` from the `rosters`, but now you have removed the element from the array so the length is been changed.